# How to fix ‘Method kartik\form\ActiveField::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function formName() on null”?

Tags: php, yii2

How to fix `Method kartik\form\ActiveField::__toString()` ?

It must not throw an exception, caught Error:

> Call to a member function formName() on null

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have error **Call to a member function formName() on null** It means that this method is not called on the object like:

```
$obj->formName();
```

It this case looks like `$obj === null` and an error tell it.

*Check where and how an object is created.*